# urllib.urlopen won't execute on a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, urllib

I'm working with threads and I need to download a website with a thread. I also have a thread that sends the petition to the site but doesn't wait for an answer.
The one that doesn't wait is this:

```
class peticion(Thread):
    def __init__(self, url):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.url = url

    def run(self):
        f = urllib.urlopen(self.url)
        f.close()
```

This one works correctly, however the one that has to wait for the response takes something like a random time to complete, from 5 seconds to 2 minutes, or it may never finish. This is the class:

```
class playerConn(Thread):
    def __init__(self, ev):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ev = ev

    def run(self):
        try:
            params = urllib.urlencode('''params go here''')
            f = urllib.urlopen('''site goes here''')
            resp = f.read()
            f.close()
        finally:
            # do something with the response
```

Whether or not I use the try...finally statement it doesn't work, the code after the `urlopen` function won't get to execute.

What can I do?

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked for me, basically as written. Maybe check for an error with opening the url, like a 404 or something?

Answer (score 0):

It appear to just be a problem with the URL, the code is fine and it does not appear to do something wrong.
I bet you have some type of problem from the website, maybe a 404 or similar.
Try opening something in localhost, just to test.